# How to make more secure SSL pinning in iOS?

Tags: ios, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have successfully implement SSL pinning in my application as below:
https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/how-to-make-your-ios-apps-more-secure-with-ssl-pinning

But in this approach, I have to placed my certificates in the app bundle on the client side. During the every request I will check or match it with server certificates in the form of  NSData. It is working fine.

Problems/Queries:

1. Certificates which is placed in app bundle, Can easily access by anybody just extract the iPA.
2. Every time when server certificates changes, I have to update certificates on client also and release a new iPA.

Please correct or suggest me the best way to overcome above two problems.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1: Who cares? A public certificate is public by definition. Anyway you can use the sha-256 hash of the certificate to save space and compare that. 2: That is the disadvantage of leaf certificate pinning. An alternative way would be leaf public key pinning. Whe renewing the certificate the key usually stays the same.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your valuable comment. It's helpful for me if you explain more about suggested way "leaf public key pinning" in point 2 as per your comment.

Comment: Every certificate includes a public key, and instead of pining the whole certificate you can extract the public key and use it for pinning.

Comment: @Robert any reference or link regarding the implementation by using key in place of certificates.